# Triple underlining

Tags: soul, text-decorations, ulem

I am quoting passages from ms. letters and need to underline a few words with three lines. Does a command exist for doing so? I've consulted Melchior Franz's `soul` package documentation from 2003 and Donald Arseneau's `ulem` package documentation from 2011.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the package `ulem` to create new styles.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\uuuline{\bgroup\markoverwith%
   {%
     \textcolor{red}{\rule[-0.5ex]{2pt}{0.4pt}}%
     \llap{\textcolor{blue}{\rule[-0.7ex]{2pt}{0.4pt}}}%
     \llap{\textcolor{green}{\rule[-0.9ex]{2pt}{0.4pt}}}%
   }%
   \ULon}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\uuuline{Text Text Text}
\end{document}
```

[image]